# Enumeration behaviour understanding (Intro to App Development with Swift - Lesson 19)

Tags: swift, enumeration

I'm new to coding and am about to finish the "Intro to App Development with Swift" iBook. I am currently in lesson 19, Enumerations and Switch and, at page 8 of the associated playground it shows the following code:

```
enum LunchChoice {
    case pasta, burger, soup
}

func cookLunch(_ choice: LunchChoice) -> String {
    if choice == .pasta {
        return ""
    } else if choice == .burger {
        return ""
    } else if choice == .soup {
        return ""
    }

    return "Erm... how did we get here?"
}

cookLunch(.soup)
```

Per se, this is not a problem for me to understand but, once I call `cookLunch(.soup)`, the last return statement doesn't show up.
The exercise just below ask me:

> try to change the value passed in to cookLunch so that the final else statement is called

And that is where I got stuck because it seems impossible to pass something different to the cookLunch function other than the choices present in the enumeration.

Could you help me understand the sense behind all this and maybe provide me a solution?

Comment: If you pass in the value of .soup, the las clause would be triggered.  As an aside - a better way of doing this would be with a switch statement instead of an if else.

Comment: Yes, that was the way of the book to explain that a switch would have been better. But still, the last clause doesn't appear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructions say "so that the final else statement is called". That would be the soup return, not the "how did we get here" return. As you say, with 3 lunch choices and 3 if/else statements, one of them will always be invoked. You have to add a 4th lunch choice that doesn't have a corresponding if or else if in order for the "how did we get here" code to execute.

Comment: Your explanation ought to be in their lesson. Pretty tricky thing for a beginner to have to figure out.

Comment: The point is: if I cancel the last 'return' statement (how did we get there), the whole function will throw me an error. The exercise already provides the cookLunch.soup to call the 'last' statement but tells me to change something so that the last sentence will be called. So ... how?

Comment: No. You can't ever get to the "how did we get here" line with the code you posted. The compiler isn't quite smart enough to know that, however. It thinks there might be a case where execution falls through all the `if` cases and gets to the end. The compiler insists that you provide a return value for every possible "execution path", so it gives you an error.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Comment out the third comparison

  ```
  // } else if choice == .soup {
  //      return ""
  ```
- Add a fourth case which is not covered by the comparisons

  ```
  enum LunchChoice {
      case pasta, burger, soup, steak
  }
  ```

  and pass it:

  ```
  cookLunch(.steak)
  ```

---

However nobody would seriously write such an `if - else` chain, in Swift a `switch` expression is appropriate

```
func cookLunch(_ choice: LunchChoice) -> String {
    switch choice {
    case .pasta:  return ""
    case .burger:  return ""
    case .soup: return ""

    default: return "Erm... how did we get here?"
    }
}
```

Comment: And the benefit then comes from not providing the default which is a check to make sure that you are handling all the possible provided values.